# How card / e-payment friendly is Dubai

Tags: payment-cards, dubai

I am travelling to Dubai for a weekend to check out the expo and wondering whether to convert and hold physical cash.

How card friendly is the economy any idea? Eg some places like India or China or Thailand almost anyone accepts cards even for relatively small transactions.

Other countries like Germany they will look at you like an alien if you proffer a card.

Just curious what the Dubai situation is.

Comment: I guess your information of Germany is either outdated or regional. I was in Germany 15 years ago and even then I paid a lot by card and that has been going up during covid.

Comment: @Willeke I guess it's all relative. But compared to Scandinavia or India or China or even the US my impression was that Germany was reluctant to accept credit cards especially for lower value transactions.

Comment: I haven't been to Germany in the last couple of years but beside the love affair with cash, one issue has long been the difference between local debit cards and the credit cards everyone else has. Even a MasterCard or Visa *debit* card would be refused in places that take “EC-Karte” (technially Girocard, now mostly co-branded with Maestro) so that locals would not even grasp the problem. The Netherlands was the same: In the 2000s, it was nearly impossible to use the train network or pay at supermarkets with foreign cards but it's been getting better for some years now.

Comment: Maestro made some level of international use possible for these debit cards and I think Dutch and German Maestro cards are interoperable but there are many banks / countries that do not issue them at all (and Mastercard wants to kill it anyway).

Answer (score 4):

I was in Dubai two years ago, and credit card worked everywhere - except if you walk through the souks (markets) and try to buy something small or street food.

Answer (score 2):

Dubai is a very modern city. In my personal experience, it's very well developed compared to any other place in the world. You will never need to pay with Cash in most of the places. The card is accepted almost everywhere. If you are still worried then have hard cash in dollars. It's easy to get dollars converted and the rates you get are better than any other currency.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed cards were ubiquitous and everyone accepted them.

I even had a interesting experience where a vending machine accepted 2.5 AED ( a fraction of a dollar) by a credit card and that too in tap mode.

Fascinating indeed.